# Meaning of domain, application in URL

Tags: java, web-applications

what is the meaning of the "abc", "def" in the URL: http://abc.def.xyz.com . I understand xyz is called domain. I read somewhere abc is an application. How can i configure like this and where is it made? In a Java webapp, is it made in web.xml since i have not come across anything like that so far. Or is it made in servlet container/application server. 
Any information on this is appreciated.

Comment: They have no special meaning whatsoever. They are just hostname components. Even `com` is a hostname component; it just happens that it is the first and as such has a special role and a dedicated name (TLD). Read about how DNS works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"abc" and "def" are subdomains of "xyz", which in turn is a subdomain of the top-level domain "com". But domains directly under a top-level domain are rarely referred to as a subdomains.

Basically you can bind your domain names to whatever you want, it doesn't have to be a specific application.

Example:

Let's say you have your own personal domain *mydomain.com*, which is bound to the IP-address of your home router. You could have *phone.mydomain.com* point to the IP-address of your phone, *www.mydomain.com* to your remotely hosted web server and *laptop.mydomain.com* to your laptop. This is all set up by a *DNS host* (the name itself is managed by a *registrar*).

In other words, it has nothing to do with your application (aside from the convention of pointing certain domain names to the server hosting your application). Although I guess it's possible to have *app1.mydomain.com* and *app2.mydomain.com* point to the same application server, which then does some internal routing based on subdomains...

Answer (score 0):

Calling 'abc' application it is only convention. There are no technical reason behind.

Technically speaking `abc.def.xyz.com` is domain name. As well as `def.xyz.com`, `xyz.com` and even `com`.

If you interest in this topic you can read further about [domain names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name)